# Which SSL Ciphers Should I Remove in Tomcat for the Poodle (SSL3) Vulnerability

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Which ciphers in my Tomcat's server.xml do I need to remove to be safe from the Poodle vulnerability?  Anything that says SSL?

```
ciphers="
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

Comment: POODLE isn't about a bad cipher either, it's a bad protocol version. You remove *not a single* cipher to be safe. You disallow connections with the old protocol: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shellshock has nothing to do with TLS.
And for POODLE you should not remove any ciphers either, but just disallow Protocol version SSL 3.0.